# How to modify data of select query before inserting from one table to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables Temp and Final. I want to insert data from temp table to final table. There is already a complex query written for that.

```
INSERT INTO public.Final 
(
  select id, class, type, meta_id, time, zone, geom 
  from public.Temp where ....
)
```

Now I want to add further criteria on geometry where in I want to merge polygons and then remove overlapping geometries. I have 2 separate queries written for those tasks. I can't combine into one select as it is already complex.

These queries I want to apply before inserting data into final table. Is it possible that output of one select query goes to input of another select query?

```
INSERT INTO public.Final 
(
  /*step 3 final output */
  select non overlapping geometries where ...
  (/*step 2*/
    select merged geometries 
    where ...
     (/*step 1*/select valid geometries where ...)
   )
)
```

If you could give me any example on how to do it, that would be great! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are multiple ways , but needs more detail to know better which way is suitable for your case :

1. using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT * FROM COMPLEXQUERY1) AS Q1
JOIN (SELECT * FROM COMPLEXQUERY2) AS Q2
 ON Q1.ID = Q2.ID 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM COMPLEXQUERY3) AS Q3
 ON Q2.ID = Q3.ID
```

2. using `IN` and/or `EXISTS IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT * FROM COMPLEXQUERY1) AS Q1
WHERE EXISTS 
( 
   SELECT * FROM COMPLEXQUERY2 Q2
    WHERE Q1.ID = Q2.ID 
    AND Q2.ID2 IN 
       ( 
          SELECT id from COMPLEXQUERY3
       )
)
```